# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token Illegal

Tags: wp-admin, admin, errors, localhost

I have a local install of Wordpress running & I am suddenly getting these errors in my console when I open a modal window (such as file upload):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
media-upload.php:75Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
media-upload.php:89Uncaught ReferenceError: SWFUpload is not defined
media-upload.php:156Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
load-scripts.php:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Non-wordpress site's work fine and I've never had any issues like this before, it seems to be limited to Wordpress.

What I don't understand is that the modal window is being called and loading AJAX content, additionally all the transitions work in the rest of the Wordpress admin area.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: No plugins, fresh install of WAMP and Wordpress 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this appears to have been solved by turning on `short open tag` and `zlib output compression` in the php settings of WAMP

Comment: Also needed is the `php_zip` extension

Comment: I wish I would have read this six months ago. My local has been plagued with this. Thanks Craig!